# IOS, table header view does not hide the section header when table view scroll up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom table header view and added it to the table view, inside the table view controller programmatically. And I set that the header view will not scroll when table view scroll.
Also for each section in the table view there is a section header.
The problem is that when scrolls down, the table header view does not hide the section header.
In viewdidload, banner is a custom class inherit from UIView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
//adjust table view position
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, HeadImgHeight)];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
//add table header view
self.banner = [[Banner alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, HeadImgHeight)];
self.banner.offsetPoint = CGPointMake(ScreenWidth/2, HeadImgHeight-20);
[self.tableView addSubview:self.banner];
```

Also, since I want the header view does not disappear when scrolls, I implement the scrollViewDidScrll function

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
if (offsetY < 0) {//scroll down
    self.banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, HeadImgHeight);
    self.banner.offsetPoint = CGPointMake(ScreenWidth/2, self.banner.frame.size.height-20);

    [self.banner.MonthInComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
    [self.banner.MonthOutComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
    [self.banner.MonthInDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
    [self.banner.MonthOutDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
}else{
    if (offsetY<=30) {
        self.banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, ScreenWidth, HeadImgHeight-offsetY);
        self.banner.offsetPoint = CGPointMake(ScreenWidth/2, self.banner.frame.size.height-20);

        [self.banner.MonthInComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-offsetY, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthOutComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-offsetY, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthInDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-offsetY, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthOutDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-offsetY, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
    }else{
        self.banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, ScreenWidth, HeadImgHeight-BANNER_FLEXIBLE_LENGTH);
        self.banner.offsetPoint = CGPointMake(ScreenWidth/2, self.banner.frame.size.height-20);

        [self.banner.MonthInComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-BANNER_FLEXIBLE_LENGTH, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthOutComeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_ICON_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-BANNER_FLEXIBLE_LENGTH, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthInDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-BANNER_FLEXIBLE_LENGTH, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
        [self.banner.MonthOutDetailLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(ScreenWidth*3/4 - TITLE_WIDTH/2, HeadImgHeight-MONTH_DETAIL_BOTTOM_MARGIN-TOTAL_OUT_HEIGHT-BANNER_FLEXIBLE_LENGTH, TITLE_WIDTH, TITLE_HEIGHT)];
    }

}
```

}

[screen shot when no scroll][1]

[screen shot when scroll down, no problem][2]

[screen shot when scroll up, as you can see the section header is over the table header view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4PNu.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: I can not tell what the actual problem is here. But the section headers are not meant to scroll up until you the next section reaches the top. At this point the section header whose section you where scrolling then scrolls up (away).

Comment: If you section headers to scroll you might as well make them tableview cells and not header views (just a suggestion if that is what you are after).